# How to convert an array with data objects to just an array with strings with javascripts?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to convert an array with data objects to just an array with strings with javascripts.
This is the data set below

```
const Cars = [
      { carTypes: 'Cadillac' },
      { carTypes: 'Jaguar' },
      { carTypes: 'Audi' },
      { carTypes: 'Toyota' },
      { carTypes: 'Honda' },
    ];
```

This is the results i would like to get `const models = ['Cadillac', 'Jaguar', 'Audi', 'Toyota', 'Honda'];`

I tried this below but it didn't work

```
 function OnFucTap() {
    const Cars = [
      { carTypes: 'Cadillac' },
      { carTypes: 'Jaguar' },
      { carTypes: 'Audi' },
      { carTypes: 'Toyota' },
      { carTypes: 'Honda' },
    ];

    const models = Cars.carTypes.split(',');

    console.log(models);
    alert(models);
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map()` to access each object's `carTypes` element.

```
const models = Cars.map(car => car.carTypes);
```

If `carTypes` could contain a comma-separated list of manufacturers, you can use `split()` on the property and `flatMap()` to concatenate all of them.

```
const models = Cars.flatMap(car => car.carTypes.split(','));
```

BTW, names like `Toyota` and `Honda` are makes. Models are `Camry` and `Accord`.